# jQueryMobile with MVC framework in Java EE context

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am planning to develop a mobile web application for one of the biz requirement. I am thinking of using jQueryMobile frame work. Which whould be
ideal MVC framework which can work in conjuction with jQueryMobile. This is going to be in Java EE environment.

This project is kind of an integration project with LMS. The LMS is having standard API. Which would be the best MVC framework in Java EE context to work
with jQueryMobile. Please kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use an MVC framework in a Java EE environment, both Struts2 or Spring MVC would be suitable. They are both full frameworks that fulfil pretty much every requirement developers have for building websites, including serving a jquery mobile web app.

You'd be able to use either frameworks' implementations of JSON data transfer and you'd have full localization, validation, security, database back-end communication and transactions, error handling.

The learning curve is quite steep though. If you have any experience in one or the other, that would be the best to go for, unless you have plenty of time to look into it, although the advantages of one over the other are likely to be small. Your choice is unlikely to be swayed by LMS and its API, for which either framework would provide a suitable place to code the interaction.